# Python : error - The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python

I wrote:

```
if merge_files['responsibility_index_num_x']<31:
    merge_files['Key']=='1-31'
```

and got the following error:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Could you please advise?

I tried this instead but getting the same error:

```
merge_files.loc[merge_files[(merge_files['responsibility_index_num_x'] >0) & (merge_files['responsibility_index_num_x'] < 31)], 'key'] = '1-30'
```

Comment: This has to be the fifth such question about this that I've opened today. Did you google the error? What did you understand from the results?

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown when you want to get the bool of a pandas.Series:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> x = pd.Series([1])
>>> bool(x)
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What you hit was a place where the operator implicitly converted the operands to bool (you used `if` but it also happens for `and`, `or` and `while`):

```py
>>> df or df
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
>>> df and df
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
>>> if df:
...     print('fun')
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
>>> while df:
...     print('fun')
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

For you, you need to do:

```py
merge_files.loc[(merge_files['responsibility_index_num_x'] > 0) &
                (merge_files['responsibility_index_num_x'] < 31), 'key'] = '1-30'
```

Note: If there is an indentation error, just remove the 'neat' formatting that I did for the last code.

Comment: Thanks! The modified code you shared worked well :)